# How do I implement draggable after reducing the height of the elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to reduce the height of a div and make it draggable using jquery-ui-draggable. This is what I have done in JS

```
 $(".sortable").sortable({
      revert: true,
      start : function (){
        $(".qhide").css("height","60px");
        $(".qhide").css("overflow","hidden");
      },
      stop : function(){
        $(".qhide").css("height","");   
        $(".qhide").css("overflow","none");
      }
    });
```

My html is something like this

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="row">
     Some content here
        <div class="qhide">some more content here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is this is that although the height reduces in the view, the height that is taken for the drag is the original height of the div (meaning that i have to drag a div way below in the page to make it move down in the condensed structure). Is there any way I can change this?

Comment: Are you trying to set the height of all of the elements with the `.qhide` class or just the element being dragged?

Comment: all of them. because i want all my rows to be condensed so that the user can see them.

Comment: You want the parent container to condense as well then?

Comment: which element are you referring to by parent container?

Comment: In your case it would be `<div class="sortable">`, am I correct that is the element that you want to shrink but isn't?

Comment: no i don't want the parent container to condense. I want to condense all the dives titled `qHide` below the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach**

I did a few modifications to the sortable objects in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/yRK5D/) so you could see and test some different things you could do.

But the specific code you are looking for is below:

**HTML**

```
start: function () {
    $('.qhide').addClass('collapse');
},
stop: function () {
    $('.qhide').removeClass('collapse');
}
```

**CSS**

```
.collapse {
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This solution will be more efficient as the browser only has to find the `.qhide` elements once on start and stop instead of twice.

*This is tested and working in fiddle, if you are still running into issues let me know there may be another problem.*